# how to read data from table (sapui5)?

Tags: sapui5

I have a table that I'm populating using a json model. Once the data is in I try to grab that data from the table. The problem is that I can't grab the rows. When I do so it returns null for some reason. I'm able to get columns but not rows, which is odd.

Here is my code.

```
  <t:Table
        id="searchResultsTable"
        visible="true"
        selectionMode="MultiToggle"
        rows="{path: 'products>/ProductCollection'
              }"
        showNoData="true"
        ariaLabelledBy="title">
        <t:columns>
            <t:Column
                id="awdDateColumn"
                sortProperty="AwdDate"
                width="11%"
                resizable="false">
                <Label text="Awd Date">
                </Label>
                <t:template>
                    <Text text="{path: 'products>AwdDate',
                                type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
                                formatOptions: {source: {pattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}, style: 'long'}}"/>
                </t:template>
            </t:Column>
            <t:Column
                id="PPICostColumn"
                sortProperty="PPICost"
                width="7%"
                resizable="false">
                <Label text="PPI Cost">
                </Label>
                <t:template>
                    <Text text="{products>PPICost}"/>
                </t:template>
            </t:Column>
            <t:Column
                id="histCostColumn"
                sortProperty="HistCost"
                width="7%"
                resizable="false">
                <Label text="Hist Cost">
                </Label>
                <t:template>
                    <Text text="{products>HistCost}"/>
                </t:template>
            </t:Column>
            <t:Column
                id="piinColumn"
                sortProperty="PIIN"
                width="10%"
                resizable="false">
                <Label text="PIIN">
                </Label>
                <t:template>
                    <Link
                        text="{products>PIIN}"
                        press="handleLinkPress" app:mydata="{products>HistPPI},{products>Qty},{products>AwdDate},{products>TransactionNumber}" />
                </t:template>
            </t:Column>
            <t:Column
                id="histPPIColumn"
                sortProperty="HistPPI"
                width="7%"
                resizable="false">
                <Label text="Hist PPI">
                </Label>
                <t:template>
                    <Text text="{products>HistPPI}"/>
                </t:template>
            </t:Column>
            <t:Column
                id="currentPPIColumn"
                sortProperty="CurrentPPI"
                width="7%"
                resizable="false">
                <Label text="Curr PPI">
                </Label>
                <t:template>
                    <Text text="{products>CurrentPPI}"/>
                </t:template>
            </t:Column>
            <t:Column
                id="PPIFactorColumn"
                sortProperty="PPIConversionFactor"
                width="7%"
                resizable="false">
                <Label text="PPI Factor">
                </Label>
                <t:template>
                    <Text text="{products>PPIConversionFactor}"/>
                </t:template>
            </t:Column>
            <t:Column
                id="TransactionNumberColumn"
                width="10%"
                visible="false"
                resizable="false">
                <Label text="Transaction #">
                </Label>
                <t:template>
                    <Text text="{products>TransactionNumber}"/>
                </t:template>
            </t:Column>
        </t:columns>
    </t:Table>
```

Here's my javascript where I try to grab the data.

```
  var table = this.byId('searchResultsTable');
      var aItems = table.getRows(); //this doesn't work

      var cols = table.getColumns(); //this works
```

can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you. I have recreated your table and I do get the list of rows [HERE](http://jsbin.com/zomoyexaje/1/edit?html,output) using your code.

Comment: Yup, I'm really confused because I have this exact code in another app and it works with no issues. So I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: It must be something that is not in the listed code. What error do you get when trying to get the rows?

Comment: when I console.log() aItems I get []. If I expand the object shown it says it's an array of 0. If I try to do   var cells = aItems.[0].getCells(); to get the items from the table I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCells' of undefined". I have this code on a different app and it works fine. There is probably something else going on that I don't get.